# GoMaps and Google API Key

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that makes heavy use of Google Maps.  We are currently using GoMaps as a wrapper around the Google Maps V3 API and it works pretty well.  However, when we went to production and I followed the docs on Google's site to add our API it didnt work.  We get the following error message:
"Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps JAvascript API V3 on this site......"

We are loading Google Maps & Go Maps in the following manner (ASP.NET MVC4 Razor):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@Model.GoogleKey&sensor=false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.js")"></script>
```

@Model.GoogleKey is the key from the email that Google sent us.  Based on reading this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial (Obtaining an API Key) the above should work.

Or is there additional work we need to do?  Do I need to encrypt the API key somehow?
Is there something in GoMaps that will take care of this? I've looked but didnt see anything.

Any help would be greatly apperciated.

TIA

Comment: I think you're missing the example of how you're implementing it

Comment: Just realized 1 issue - we have a business license.  Reading those docs now, but I'm not sure if it will work w/ GoMaps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a business license is slightly different. Check out the docs here:
http://goo.gl/WFztZ

But basically you want:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&client=gme-yourclientid&sensor=true_or_false&channel=yourchannel"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

replace `key` with `client` and add a channel if appropriate